# opentok how to hide the publisher video display

Tags: opentok

I am using OpenTok and I am trying to swich with video display on/off.
So I use the following pubOptions

```html
  var pubOptions;
  if (show_video) 
  {
   pubOptions= null;   
  }
  else
  {
   pubOptions= { videoSource: null,  style: {buttonDisplayModeo: 'off'}};
  }
  //Replace the first parameter with the replacement element ID:
  session.on("streamCreated", function(event) 
  {
   session.subscribe(event.stream);
  });
  session.connect(token, function(error) 
  {
   publisher = OT.initPublisher("publisher_text",pubOptions);
   session.publish(publisher);
  });
```

But the video window is displayed in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following documentation: https://tokbox.com/opentok/tutorials/audio-video/js/#publish_audio_video_only

If you want to disable video after publishing, you'll need:

```
publisher.publishVideo(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/js/reference/OT.html#initPublisher

I believe you want `pubOptions = {publishVideo: false, style:{buttonDisplayMode: 'off'}};`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you're looking for is this but you may try it...

session.unpublish(); //unpublishes your stream/video

session.forceUnpublish(); //unpublished your strea/video and forces other streams to be unpublished as well